# Laravel - how do you inject variables into the password reminder email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.1's new password broker, is there a way to pass some data to the password reminder view? Specifically I want to be able to alter the URL of the password reset view.

Looking here: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Reminders.PasswordBroker.html#97-118 I am not sure it is flexible enough to accept data without fully extending this class...

Comment: Did you find a clean way to do this?

Comment: I added this to the PasswordBroker file and it works, although that is really not the best place for it, but I am having trouble passing it in otherwise.    $m->subject('Reset your password')->to($user->getReminderEmail());

Comment: thanks @Jason. I am kind of shocked that there is not a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the code suggested by searsaw didn't work for me. I think I get something wrong. But I found next solution:

```
    View::composer('emails.auth.reminder', function($view) use ($user) {
        $view->with([
            'first_name'  => $user->first_name,
            'email'       => $user->email,
            'newPassword' => Input::get('new_password'),
            'logo'         => asset('/images/mail/logo.png'),
            'twitter_img'  => asset('/images/mail/btn_twitter_pressed.png'),
            'facebook_img' => asset('/images/mail/btn_fb_pressed.png')
        ]);
    });
```

I use this code before `Password::remind` method

Comment: So calling that View::composer() on that particular view will trigger the view being changed when Password::remind() is called and sends that view?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i fully get the question, but if you want to pass some extra data, you can use the code like this in Laravel:
`
$activation = [];

$activation['email'] = $email;

$activation['subject'] = 'Some info';

Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', $data, function($message) use ($activation)

{

$message->to($activation['email'])->subject($activation['subject']);

});`

Comment: that is a simple email send. in this case, we wanted to pass some data to the Password::remind() view. this is done with View::composer() as @Victor said below

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the array that is given to the reminder method will be passed to the reminder view.  You could pull out alot of this logic and do everything manually.

```
$user = Password::getUser(Input::get('email'));

$remind_repo = App::make('Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderRepositoryInterface');
$token = $remind_repo->create($user);

$data['name'] = 'Forest Gump';
$data['likes'] = ['running', 'chocolates'];
$data['girlfriend'] = 'Jenny';
$data['user'] = $user;
$data['token'] = $token;

Mail::send('email.reminder', $data, function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->getReminderEmail());
});
```

Now your view will have access to `name`, `likes`, `girlfriend`, `user`, and `token`.

Comment: First I got an error that Password::getUser expects an array as an argument. I used User::where instead. But then I got this error: Target [Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable. :(